# Robust/Tested Solver for incompressible 2D Euler (Fluid dynamics) Equation

Tags: optimization, fluid-dynamics, optimal-control

I am trying to locate suitable computational algorithms for a optimization problem that requires repeated solution of transient 2D incompressible Euler equation on a 2D domain (say rectangular).

**My question is whether an off-the-shelf PDE solver can solve incompressible Euler equations on 2D domains in a robust manner, or if there are any customized solvers for 2D incompressible Euler.**

Comment: The solution to your problem doesn't require a computer code -- it is $\mathbf u_0=0$ since then the velocity field is and remains zero, and the points $\mathbf x_i$ do not move -- making your objective function zero. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Thanks for noticing the error. I edited my question so it makes more sense

Comment: I see. I don't know of any code that could do this, and I think it's also a really difficult problem to solve since there are likely many local solutions to the minimization problem -- think of rotating the imaging by 180 degrees in your disk domain: you can choose an initial condition that rotates clockwise or counterclockwise, and you can also rotate by 540, 900, ... degrees.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I am fine with local optimal solutions. My main question is about the Euler solver: are there some available Euler-equation solvers I can use that can be used to reliably generate particle trajectories needed for evaluating the terms in cost.

Comment: I have to admit that I don't know.

Comment: Why not formulate the adjoint to find the gradient of your cost function? Your design or forcing would be the initial condition.

Comment: @SpencerBryngelson Yes, I would need to form an adjoint equation. The resulting forward-adjoint system will need to be solved. The forward equation will involve the Euler equation, hence the question in my post.

Comment: This type of problem might be solvable with [dolfin-adjoint](http://www.dolfin-adjoint.org/en/latest/). This is probably not an off the shelf solver and requires that you at least implement the forward problem  in [fenics](https://fenicsproject.org/). This [example](http://www.dolfin-adjoint.org/en/latest/documentation/tutorial.html#dolfin-adjoint-tutorial) might get you started.

Comment: I am looking for forward solver for 2D Euler equation. The adjoint formulation I can work out myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are solving inviscid equations, you will need some form of stabilization like SUPG or a DG scheme, to get a robust scheme. You wont need the pressure I presume. I would recommend solving the equations in vorticity-velocity form where the pressure is eliminated. See this paper for a DG scheme

Jian-Guo Liu and Chi-Wang Shu, A High-Order Discontinuous Galerkin Method for 2D Incompressible Flows, Journal of Computational Physics 160(2):577-596, August 1999, DOI: 10.1006/jcph.2000.6475